# Most popular hour of unixtime

Tags: mysql

I have a db table with about a half-million rows of user sign in data.

simple db table:

```
users_signin:
    id
    userid
    datetime
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to acquire the average, or most common, hour of day that a specific person signs into the website.

I am wanting to have a "hour" returned, such as: 04 or 23  (4am/11pm).

The `datetime` field is a unix time stamp

I have fiddled around doing avg() but getting just the **hour** is where I am hitting a wall at.

Comment: Have you tried [`Hour()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)?

Comment: I had not tried that. I tried a very simple `select hour(`datetime`) as hour from users_iplog where `usersname` = 'some_users_name' limit 10;` and I got the same results as what I posted in the response to Gordon below.

Comment: How about `HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))`?

Comment: Ah!!   There we go:  `SELECT AVG( HOUR( FROM_UNIXTIME( DateTime ) ) ) AS HOUR`   returns, for example, `11.9201`  woot, thanks @PM77-1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most common hour of the day for a specific user, you can try the following query:

```
select hour(datetime) as hr, count(*)
from simple
where userid = $userid
group by hour(datetime)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

EDIT:

If the thing you are calling `datetime` is really a unix time, then you should do:

```
select hour(from_unixtime(datetime)) as hr, count(*)
from simple
where userid = $userid
group by hour(from_unixtime(datetime))
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: That returned `NULL` so I increased the limit to 10 and got:

NULL
NULL
838
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
838

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE simple` -- we need to see the datatype of `datetime`.

Comment: @abela . . . The query could not return multiple `NULL` values because of the `group by`.